# VBA Adding Records to the Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I click on the add command button by default it's adding in the third row of the sheet. It should be added to the first available row. Is it something i need to change in the VBA code or the Button Properties?

```
Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = Sheet1
    Set AddNew = wks.Range("AA1000000").End(xlup).Offset(1, 0)
    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtcustomerid.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtContract.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtContractLBS.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtContractPrice.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtItem.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = Txtitemnum.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = TxtCustomerName.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = Txtstartdate.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = Txtenddate.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 9).Value = TxtSalesPerson.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 10).Value = TxtBroker.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 11).Value = TxtTerms.Text
    End Sub
```

Comment: Right now, the code should be finding the next available row, **based on the data in column "AA"**. If that column doesn't always have data, you may need to use a range from a different column.

Comment: Just a heads-up I see you have `.End(x1up)` instead of `.End(xlup)`

Comment: i did changed but it's still pointing to the next row. @MichaelMurphy

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ActiveSheet.UsedRange, see:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

I suspect your current issue is due presence of formatting data, or lack of data in column AA - that may be a typo in your code?

Comment: If you have a column you trust to always be populated, `.End(xlUp)` is a solid way to do it. Used Range is useful but not always completely accurate. For instance, formatting on the bottom row of the data can cause Excel to include the first empty row in the Used Range.

Comment: i did changed but it's still pointing to the next row @MarkBalhoff

Comment: @Jennifer I'm operating a little blind here as I haven't seen the spreadsheet but I'd guess that column AA doesn't have any values after the second row as Mistella said (you aren't putting any data in that column in the method you are showing us). That's the 27th column. Did you mean column A? If that doesn't fix it, double check that this method is attached as the event handler for clicking the button.